# Handbrake can't access my video files

Tags: permissions, handbrake

I have permissions set in Handbrake to have access to files in 'home'. When I try to access my Videos folder it is denied.

The only thing I can think is the Videos is a sym link to /mnt/hdd/Videos - as I had to use a separate disc because of space issues. The sym link works seamlessly for all other things and other apps, e.g. Kdenlive, don't have the same issue.

Ideas gratefully welcomed (I've just got Da Vinci Resolve working after much trial and error, only to find it won't work with .mkv files!)

Thanks

```
roger@roger-ubuntu:~$ ls -l V* 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 roger roger   15 Jan 27  2020  Videos -> /mnt/hdd/Videos
```

Edit - permissions

```
drwxrwxrwx 15 roger roger    16384 Nov  7 17:01  Videos
lrwxrwxrwx  1 roger roger      15 Jan 27  2020  Videos -> /mnt/hdd/Videos
```

Comment: How did you install Handbrake?

Comment: What are the permissions on `/mnt/hdd/Videos`?  If `handbrake` is running as a different user (and NOT as `roger`) then it might not have permissions to access the mounted folder.  Symlinks don't override the permissions on the actual destination either, so you need permissions to read the destination as is anyways, not just have the symlink.

Comment: Permissions look the same to me. Original post updated.

Comment: I installed Handbrake from the Ubuntu software centre.

Comment: You needed to open Software Centre, find Handbrake, and give it permissions to access your external drives.

Answer (score 1):

I deleted it and installed it via apt and now it works.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a permissions issue. Either your file has read-only permission, or you dont have that specific partition or media mounted, or your application doesn't have enough permissions (this can be fix by going into Software Centre, finding the application and "permissions". My Memory on how to do this is quite blurry since I rarely had these problems)). I am just giving you the ideas of what the problem might be to help you out on finding out the solution. I hope this has helped you out a bit.